# "Сойти" или "выйти"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Грамотно ли говорить "**сойти** на такой-то остановке"? Или все-таки надо говорить "**выйти**"?
И отсюда же: грамотно ли спрашивать: **"Вы сходите?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько помнится, "сойти" означает "спуститься" (сойти на берег, сойти с крыльца, сойти с небес...) или в переносном значении типа "сойти с ума". Что касается "выйти", то это слово означает "покинуть какое-то помещение, состояние (выйти из дома, выйти замуж). Так что следует говорить "выйти на такой-то остановке", "вы выходите?". Правда, в речевой практике часто и в этих случаях говорят "сойти", но это уже относится в какой-то мере к речевому этикету.

Comment: Хотя это и считается неверным, но объяснимо: ведь, выходя из автобуса (троллейбуса, электрички и т.д.), мы тоже  спускаемся по ступенькам, как и с крыльца.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то все зависит от того, **в чем** или **на чем** вы едете.
Если ***в*** автобусе — то выйти. А если ***на*** автобусе — то сойти.
Почему-то это простая логика не приходит в голову ретивым ревнителям "выйти" из любого общественного транспорта, зачастую включая поезд и судно (корабль).
Так что я бы поостерегся записывать "сойти" в очевидную безграмотность. 
Пока что "выйти" однозначно необходимо только для "выйти из такси" — да и то только тогда, когда речь не идёт о кузове грузового такси.

ЗЫ Хотя и с такси в принципе рано или поздно может возобладать означенная логика. Мы же не ***в*** такси ездим, а ***на*** нем.

ЗЫ Специально для Лекусеньки и других, если кто не понял насчет нормативности.
Обычно этот вопрос задается в связи с конкретной ситуацией толпы у дверей перед остановкой. Там действительно нормативен один-единственный вариант. И я никогда ни сам не спрошу, ни другим не посоветую говорить "Вы на следующей сходите?" Но здесь однозначен контекст. Мы все находимся *внутри* вагона или чего уж там бывает у всяких автобусов-троллейбусов-фуникулеров. Поэтому — только "Вы выходите?". Но в остальных случаях возможны контекстно-зависимые варианты.

Comment: behemothus пишет: "Если в автобусе - то выйти. А если на автобусе - то сойти". Мы находимся Внутри ( В автобусе, В трамвае, В каюте), и выходим, естественно ИЗ троллейбуса и пр. Неважно, НА чем я еду: НА автобусе, трамвае или НА поезде. ВЫйду я все равно ИЗ вагона. Глаголы с приставкой ВЫ будут управлять существительным с предлогом ИЗ. О предлогах антониах (На остров - с острова) -это "немного" не сюда.

Comment: Ну это-то я понял. Вы сейчас повторили мнения тех самых обывателей, которым я и предлагал посмотреть на вещи незашорено.
Но Вы возражаете тому, чего я не говорил. Я ни секудны не сомневаюсь, что "выходят из", а "сходят с". Более т ого, я это положил в основы рассуждений. 

Я сажусь **на** австобус. Я еду **на** автобусе. Следовательно, когда я покидаю автобус будет предлог **с**. Естественно, что и глагол будет сойти, а не выйти: я схожу **с** автобуса.

Аналогично:

Я сажусь **в** австобус. Я еду **в** автобусе. Я выхожу *из* автобуса.

Comment: Насчет "внутри". Скажите, а в поезде я разве не внутри нахожусь? Или **на** судне? Никода не слышал, чтобы из судна выходили. Всегда - сойти на берег (причал). Да и с поезда я скорее схожу, а не выхожу.

Не знаю уж, как еще объяснить...

Чего вот не понял, это почему "не сюда". Именно сюда. Если НА - то С. Если В, то ИЗ. Исключений нет.

И ещё Вы забыли сказать, какой все-таки логикой вы бы советовали руководствоваться обывателям.

Answer (score 1):

Причем тут "на автобусе" или "в автобусе"? Выйти ИЗ автобуса - сойти, получается "С автобуса". Как раз сойти " с трамвая, с автобуса, с троллейбуса" - это все-таки ненормативно. "Такая простая логика", как у behemothus, присуща к сожалению, большинству обывателей...

Comment: Я не очень понимаю Ваш комментарий, но очень даже при чем.  
Предлоги В/НА (в соответвующих значениях) строго соотвевуют предлогам-антонимам ИЗ/С. Точно также они определяют и выбор глагола сойти или выйти. Невозможно сойти оттуда, *в* чем вы находитесь, только выйти (ну если речь не идёт о коровьей лепешке), как невозможно выйти оттуда, *на* чем вы стоите. 

Я был бы счаслив, если хотя бы крошечная часть "обывателей" поднялась бы до простой логики, только не моей, а русского язвка. А какую логику Вы предлагаете обывателям? Всё, что лично Вам (или обывателю) не нравится - неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Приведу полный ответ известного лингвиста, автора "Большого толкового словаря правильной русской речи" Л. И. Скворцова (скопирована страница из словаря).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых городах (например, Воронеж) вообще говорят "Вы встаете"? Довольно странное выражение, если учесть переполненность городского транспорта, где итак большинство стоят.

Comment: Это ещё что... Однажды в московской маршрутке услышал "оставьте здесь". Думал, оговорлась дама. Оказалось - так принято в некоторых местах "нашей необъятной Родины".

Comment: Не по теме, но вспомнилось: мой любимый анекдот.  
- Вы выходите? - Да. - А перед Вами выходят? - Да. - А Вы их спрашивали? - Да. - И что они ответили?

Answer (score -1):

Выходить из автобуса, но вставать на остановке. Я так считаю. Тем более, что по-немецки, например, при дословном переводе так же вставать на остановке, а не выходить на остановке!

А сойти можно с поезда, сойти с трапа! С автобуса не сходят, а значит, не сходят и на остановке! Это какое-то мещанское "сойти на остановке" - бред!

Comment: Если вы хотите что-то добавить к своему ответу, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править". Новый ответ давать ненужно.